# Apache Directory Studio Replication only connects to the first level of tree

Tags: linux, apache, unix, ldap, apacheds

So I'm trying to setup the Apache Directory Studio Replication. So far I have it setup like the following:

Master:

```
dn: ads-serverId=ldapServer,ou=servers,ads-
directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
changetype: add
add: ads-replReqHandler
ads-replReqHandler: org.apache.directory.server.ldap.replication.provider.SyncReplRequestHandler
```

Slave:

```
dn: ads-replConsumerId={master_ip}:10389,ou=replConsumers,ads-serverId=ldapServer,ou=servers,ads-directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
ads-replconsumerid: 1
ads-replstrictcertvalidation: FALSE
ads-replusetls: FALSE
ads-replsearchtimeout: 0
ads-replsearchfilter: (objectClass=*)
ads-replsearchsizelimit: 0
ads-replattributes: *
ads-replrefreshinterval: 1000
ads-repluserpassword: secret
ads-repluserdn: uid=admin,ou=system
ads-replprovport: 10389
ads-replprovhostname: {master_ip}
ads-replrefreshnpersist: TRUE
ads-replsearchscope: sub
ads-searchbasedn: dc=apache,dc=org
ads-enabled: TRUE
objectclass: ads-replConsumer
objectclass: ads-base
objectclass: top
ads-replaliasderefmode: never`
```

It seems to be connected to the master server however I can only reach the first sub tree of data from the master. For example: on the master i have `dc=apache,dc=org` with some sub trees being `ou=groups,dc=apache,dc=org` `ou=users,dc=apache,dc=org` After these i can't see the actual individual groups and users.

Answer (score 0):

## **Update:**

It turns out I forgot to enable the NIS schema since I am using posix accounts on both master and slave servers. It was a simple fix but I'm glad that I was able to catch it.